# Session variable is not available

Tags: php

I am printing session with print_r($_SESSION) in the index page it shows following array.

```
 Array
(
    [name] => hhh
)

index.php

  <?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['name']='hhh';
```

I wanted to unset this variable whenever I want to. So I created a new php file in the same directory with the following contents

```
    <?php

    session_start();
    echo "before destroying the session";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    unset($_SESSION['name']);//remove the name session variable which is available in my index page.
    session_destroy(); //destroy the session
    echo "after destroying the session";
    print_r($_SESSION);
```

But whenever I run the above code it prints the following:

```
before destroying the sessionArray ( ) after destroying the sessionArray ( )
```

Why my session which is available in the index page is not accessible in the above script's page?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you writing it inside session_start(). Its working fine for me.

Comment: yes, it's in the first line.

Comment: do not need to session_start() again if you include index page in another page and your index page contain session start.

Comment: I am not including the above code in any file it's a separate file.

Comment: where you have define $_SESSION['name'] ?

Comment: You should post the relevant code of `index.html` as well, have you started the session there?

Comment: @ Ruchish Parikh in the index page

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your goal is, this is what your code does:

```
# You start your session
session_start();

# Echo a string
echo "before destroying the session";

# Print the $_SESSION array, comes out empty because you havn't put anything in the session
print_r($_SESSION);

# You unset the 'name' key in the $_SESSION array, which wasn't even there in the first place
unset($_SESSION['name']);

# You get rid of the session
session_destroy();

# Echo a string
echo "after destroying the session";

# You print $_SESSION variable again, which is going to be empty, because you just destroyed the session.
print_r($_SESSION);
```

My point explaining your code is, what do you actually wanna do?

If you want to use a $_SESSION across multiple pages, simply don't session_destroy() between the pages, only destroy it as your user 'logs out' so to speak and session_start() on all your pages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start session `session_start()` in your index file.

**index.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = "test";
```

**test.php**

```
include 'index.php';

    echo "before destroying the session";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    unset($_SESSION['name']);//remove the name session variable which is available in my index page.
    session_destroy(); //destroy the session
    echo "after destroying the session";
    print_r($_SESSION);
```

**Output**

```
before destroying the sessionArray ( [name] => test ) after destroying the sessionArray ( )
```

Comment: try above code to achieve your desire output. @scriptkiddie